# How can I add static values to combinations in python using "combinationUtil"?

Tags: python-3.x, recursion, combinations, permutation

This code generates all the possible combinations on the given series(r) from 1>28. I need to modify it in order to choose "x" quantity of numbers from 1>28 and leave them static while also leaving "y" quantity of numbers sorting combinations for "x". 
For example: If I want to leave three numbers static and two sorting, it would look like this:
{1 2 3 4 5}, {1 2 3 5 6}, {1 2 3 6 7}, {1 2 3 - -}, etc.

The size of a combination can be changed by modifying "r" but I can't find a way to leave static values.

Also if it's possible, what would be the best way to save all the printed combinations(printCombinations(arr, r, n)) to a .txt file?

I know that is inefficient and moronic but I'm fairly new to programming ; 
In order to make the combinations go from 1>28 I modified the structure of the "arr" only including the numbers that aren't wanted to be static. 
Example: 
In case that I want "1,2,3" to be static on the series, I need to delete them from the "arr" call: arr = [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18 , 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28];

```
def printCombination(arr, n, r): 

   combinationUtil(arr, data, 0, 
                n - 1, 0, r); 

def combinationUtil(arr, data, start, 
                end, index, r): 

if (index == r): 
    for j in range(r): 
        print(data[j], end = " "); 
    print(); 
    return; 

i = start; 
while(i <= end and end - i + 1 >= r - index): 
    data[index] = arr[i]; 
    combinationUtil(arr, data, i + 1, 
                    end, index + 1, r); 
    i += 1; 

arr = [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18 , 19, 20, 21, 
22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28]; 
r = 2; 
n = len(arr);
printCombination(arr, n, r);

 # This code is contributed by mits
```

I expect to be able to leave "x" quantity of numbers static and "y" quantity sorting all possible combinations for "x". Thanks for your patience and time. 
source: geeksforgeeks.org/print-all-possible-combinations-of-r-elements-in-a-given-array-of-size-n/

Comment: Welcome to SO! I'm having trouble following your description of the problem, but if the `x` numbers you want to omit from the array are the first, remove them and perform combinations, then tack them on to each combination. Otherwise, if the numbers could be anywhere, create a `set` of the indices you want to ignore and skip an index should you ever encounter one in your recursive function.

Comment: What I need to do is choose 3 out of 5 numbers from 1>28 and find all the posible combinations for them.

Comment: For example; If I choose : {20, 17, 7] I want it to find all the combinations without repetition.  {20, 17, 7,1,2] , {20, 17, 7, 2, 3], {20, 17, 7, 3,4], Etc.